# how to use db2 read on standby feature

Tags: jdbc, db2

IBM DB2 has a feature for HADR database - read on standby. This allows the standby database to be connected to for read-only queries (with certain restrictions on datatypes and isolation levels)

I am trying to configure this as a datasource in an application which runs on websphere liberty profile.

Previously, this application was using the Automatic Client Re-route (which ensures that all connections are directed to the current primary)

However, I would like to configure it in such a way that I can have SELECTs / read-only flows to run on the standby database, and others to run on primary. This should also work when a takeover has been performed on the database (that is, standby becoming primary and vice-versa). The purpose of doing this is to divide the number of connections created between all available databases

What is the correct way to do this?

Things I have attempted (assume my servers are dbserver1 and dbserver2):

1. Create 2 datasources, one with the db url of dbserver1 and the other with dbserver2.

   - This works until a takeover is performed and the roles of the servers are switched.
2. Create 2 datasources, one with the db url of dbserver1 (with the Automatic Client Re-route parameters) and the other with dbserver2 only.

   - With this configuration, the application works fine, but if dbserver2 becomes the primary then all queries are executed on it.
3. Setup haproxy and use it to identify which is the primary and which is the standby. Create 2 datasources pointing to haproxy

   - When takeover is carried out on the database, connection exceptions start to occur (not just at the time of takeover, but for some time following it)

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate way is described in a Whitepaper "[Enabling continuous access to read on standby databases using Virtual IP addresses](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27020912)" linked off the [Db2 documentation for Read-on-standby](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/t0054260.html).

Virtual IP addresses are assigned to both roles, primary and standby. They are cataloged as database aliases. Websphere or other clients would connect to either the primary or standby datasource. When there is a takeover or failover, the virtual IP addresses are reassigned to the specific server. The client would continue to be routed to the desired server, e.g. the standby.